# USB Host Controller for DE10-Standard FPGA (Altera Cyclone V SoC)

Tags: vhdl, fpga, intel-fpga, usb-hostcontroller

I'm Looking for a USB Host Control to connect a USB Keyboard and PS gaming controller to control program functionallity (a game) done on FPGA.

I have built a simple game in VHDL on the DE10 platform, currently controllerd using a keboard connected to the PS/2 interface (and a VHDL controller I have found on-line). Looking to expand the gaming control by connecting a USB keyboard and PS gaming controller, but I can't figure out how to build to the USB host controller in VHDL/find an existing one.

Would appriciate to know if there are exiting USB host controllers in VHDL/BSF/BDF formarts I can use to connect USB devices and get decoded information, or am I in over my head.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you expect to reuse existing USB type A socket on DE10-Standard?

Answer (score 0):

You are not only far, far in over your head, but any USB interface will need an analogue section which your FPGA does not<sup>**</sup> have.
I know from experience that USB PHY-only chips are (almost?) impossible to get.

Also where would you run the USB protocol on? And are you planning to write a USB software stack? Unfortunately these things are not that simple.

I would guess the best option would be to make a VHDL UART interface connected to a USB <=> RS323 converter cable and plug that in a PC/Raspberry-Pi or something else with a keyboard.

<sup>**</sup><sub>There are FPGAs with a USB PHY but they have the USB digital section too, as well as an on-chip processor.</sub>

Comment: /offtopic, PHY-only USB transceivers - like Microchip's USB3318 or Texas Instruments TUSB1106 - are easily obtainable from Mouser or Digikey.